# How does getAngleIncrement work in LeJOS API?

Tags: java, lejos-nxj

I'm working on a robot project using Lego NXT running the LeJOS API. I need to sum up the angles my robot makes. I found out there was a method `getAngleIncrement()` that seems to be doing just so but I can't be sure. Here's all the documentation I've found:

```
 Returns: 
     The angle rotated since rotation began.
```

But does it return all the angles since the beginning or just the angle of the rotation that is going on?

My robot needs to be aligned with other things and I used this

```
pilot.rotate(-90.0 - pilot.getAngleIncrement());
```

to make it rotate at the right angle.

Thanks!

Comment: have you tested the code? please show us the code you tried to run

Comment: @ItamarGreen  
My robot needs to bealigned with other stuff and I use this 
`pilot.rotate(-90.0 - pilot.getAngleIncrement());`
To make it rotate at the right angle

Comment: please post your entire code in the question body

Comment: what is the type of `pilot`?

Comment: It is a 'DifferentialPilot' object from the LeJOS api

Comment: to what angle do you need to align the robot?